# jenkins enviornment variable broken workspace

Tags: bash, jenkins, cygwin, continuous-integration, environment-variables

I am using Cygwin and Jenkins and trying to setup build process. In execute shell command provided the following command:

```
cd ${WORKSPACE}
```

While running the process getting an error details are:

```
cd 'C:\Program' 'Files\Jenkins\jobs\xxxx\workspace'
C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson7295054364542611971.sh: line 2: 
    cd: C:\Program: No such file or directory
```

Why the command is written as:

```
cd 'C:\Program' 'Files\Jenkins\jobs\xxxx\workspace'
```

It should be like this:

```
 cd 'C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\xxxx\workspace'
```

How can I correct this thing:

Comment: @chepner I understand but in cygwin environment how to correct this error

Comment: `cd` is currently receiving two separate arguments, `C:\Program` and `Files ...` because of the space in `Program Files`. You need to quote  the parameter expansion.